# PhoneGap and Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3, phonegap-developer-app

I have a bootstrap site build on PhoneGap. The dropdown menu works fine on desktop and web browser, but not in the PhoneGap Developer App. Does anyone have experience with this?

I can't figure out why, and I can't debug on the PhoneGap Developer App.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. All though I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it.

```
$(document).on('click touchend', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.dropdown-submenu a')) {
        $('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
        $('.dropdown-toggle').blur();
    }
});
```